# Prove Bergman's kernel formula by theorem of residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am having trouble with exercise $5$, $4.5.3$ in Ahlfors's complex analysis. I was asked to prove the Bergman's kernel formula:
\begin{equation}
f(\zeta)=\frac{1}{\pi}\iint\limits_{|z|<1}\frac{f(z)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y}{(1-\bar{z}\zeta)^{2}}
\end{equation}

under the conditions f(z) is bounded and analytic in the unit disk, moreover $\zeta$ lies in the disk. Two solutions of this problem are available on this website by using series expansion or Green's formula. However Ahlhors suggested another approach by using polar coordinates first, then transforming the inside integral into a line integral which can be evaluated by theorem of residues. I really don't know how to proceed in this way. I haved tried as following:
\begin{align}
\iint\limits_{D}\frac{f(z)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y}{(1-\bar{z}\zeta)^{2}}&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}r\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{f(z)r}{(1-\bar{z}\zeta)^{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}r\mathrm{d}r\oint\limits_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)}{(1-\bar{z}\zeta)^{2}z}\mathrm{d}z\\
\text{Since $z \bar{z}=r^{2}$}\\ &= \int_{0}^{1}r\mathrm{d}r\oint\limits_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)z}{(z-r^{2}\zeta)^{2}}\mathrm{d}z
\end{align}
At this stage, I have observed that if $\zeta=0$, then by Cauchy's theorem, the equality holds. If not, I use Residues to evaluate the contour integral and get the value $f(r^{2}\zeta)+f'(r^{2}\zeta)r^{2}\zeta$. But I stacked here because it seems impossible to get an explicit result of the integral with respect to r. Then I spent a huge amount of time trying to construct a special change of variable for the inside contour integral by a fractional linear transformation from a unit disk onto the smaller disk. But I just can not find the right linear transformation. Maybe I am on the wrong track.

Comment: First, I think somehow you squared the denominator by accident. And, I don't think you need to do a change of variables... just use the fact that _on_that_circle_, $z\cdot \overline{z}=r^2$, so you can _rearrange_ the integral to evaluate it as a path integral.

Comment: @paulgarrett I am sure that there is a square in the denominator. I have tried what you suggested, the line integral depends on r, how to evaluated the outside integral then?

Comment: Ok, yes, perhaps you edited it, but/and it seemed that on the first line the denominator started with power $1$ and then it got squared by the second. Yes, for the correct Bergman kernel, there is a square, indeed. :)

Comment: Yes that is my mistake

Comment: See on pages starting at nr. 5 of this MSThesis https://etd.ohiolink.edu/apexprod/rws_etd/send_file/send?accession=osu1461091816&disposition=inline

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you very much. I was almost there.

Comment: I think that formula is most reasonably _discovered_ by looking at series, first. After we know what it is, we can _verify_ it by these Cauchy-related manipulations (which are much less obvious, I think, than summing some series that are derivatives of geometric series). :)

Answer (score 2):

Using
$$ z=re^{i\theta} $$
one has
$$ \iint\limits_{D}\frac{f(z)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y}{(1-\bar{z}\zeta)^{2}}=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}r\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{f(re^{i\theta})r}{(1-re^{-i\theta}\zeta)^{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta=\int_{0}^{1}r\mathrm{d}r\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{2i\theta}f(re^{i\theta})}{(e^{i\theta}-r\zeta)^{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta.$$
Then using
$$z=e^{i\theta}, dz=iz\mathrm{d}\theta$$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{0}^{1}r\mathrm{d}r\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{2i\theta}f(re^{i\theta})}{(e^{i\theta}-r\zeta)^{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta= \int_{0}^{1}r\mathrm{d}r\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{z^2f(rz)}{(z-r\zeta)^{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{iz}\\
&=& -i\int_{0}^{1}r\mathrm{d}r\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{zf(rz)}{(z-r\zeta)^{2}}\mathrm{d}z=-i\int_{0}^{1}r\cdot2\pi i[f(r^2\zeta)+r^2\zeta f'(r^2\zeta)]\mathrm{d}r\tag1\\
&=&2\pi\bigg[\int_{0}^{1}rf(r^2\zeta)\mathrm{d}r+\int_{0}^{1}r^3\zeta f'(r^2\zeta)\mathrm{d}r\bigg]\\
&=&2\pi\bigg[\frac12\int_{0}^{1}f(r^2\zeta)\mathrm{d}(r^2)+\int_{0}^{1}r^3\zeta f'(r^2\zeta)\mathrm{d}r\bigg]\tag2\\
&=&2\pi\cdot\frac12f(r^2\zeta)r^2\bigg|_0^1\\
&=&\pi f(\zeta).
\end{eqnarray}
So
$$ f(\zeta)=\frac{1}{\pi}\iint\limits_{|z|<1}\frac{f(z)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y}{(1-\bar{z}\zeta)^{2}}. $$
Here in (1),
$$ zf(rz)=r\zeta f(r^2\zeta)+[f(r^2\zeta)+r^2\zeta f'(r^2\zeta)](z-r\zeta)+O((z-r\zeta)^2) $$
and in (2) the integration by parts is used.

Comment: (+1)... For (1)  one can 'just' use $$g'(a) ={1\over 2\pi i} \oint {g(z)\over (z-a)^2 }\, dz,$$ for $g$ holomorphic.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot.